# Symfony, swiftmailer, incorrect email

Tags: php, symfony, email

I use swift mailer for send email, and after send email in box I have mail without html, like in screen 
[image]

but in another mail services everything fine
this my code

```
    public function createMessage($subject, $receivers, $template, $context)
{

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance($subject);
    $message->setFrom($this->from_address);
    $message->setTo($receivers);

    $body = $this->twig->render($template, $context);
    $plaintext = strip_tags($body);
    $message->setBody($body, "text/html");
    $message->addPart($plaintext, "text/plain");

    $this->mailer->send($message);
}
```

What problem in this code? I set body test/html. What problem not understand

Comment: In your message is a `PNG` file encoded in `Base64`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public function __construct(Container $oContainer) {
    $this->oContainer = $oContainer;
}
```

> $this->oContainer->get('templating')->render()

And set the content yourself:

> $message->setContentType('text/html');